# Как сообщить MongoDB, что поле в запросе использовать не надо?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Создаю запрос, где поле 'awesome_field' должно существовать в зависимости от данных от клиента. 
Сейчас явно добавляю это поле в объект, а потом удаляю его. Хочется что-то `'awesome_field': '$$ALL'`, что бы можно было написать `'awesome_field': myVal ? myVal : '$$ALL'`

Сейчас так и это ужасно:

```
var search_query = {
   ...
  'awesome_field': myVal
};

if (conditon) delete search_query.awesome_field;

MyCollection.find(search_query)
```

'awesome_field' - в моем случае тип - Schema.Types.ObjectId

NodeJS, Mongoose v4.0.1, MongoDB 2.6.9

Comment: Если поле в запросе использовать не надо, то и, разумеется, вставлять его в запрос не надо.

Comment: "Ужасность" в коде - возможно, следствие ужасной архитектуры. Как по мне, то сойдет. Бывает и хуже. :)

Comment: Sirgio, со всем согласен. Меня беспокоит ужасность подхода. Условий много, а хочется иметь один объект запроса типа var search_query = {} и в нем определять все поля, управлять их значением и "видимостью", иначе все превращается в кашу из if'ов, switch и пр.

Comment: Ну с кашей надо бороться. Разбивать код на методы, модули, классы и тд. Сделать QueryBuilder какой-нибудь, где каша будет инкапсулирована. Или даже пачку билдеров, зависит от реальной ситуации.